# Python closes output terminal when error in code

Tags: command-line, python

I started using Ubuntu few days ago primarly for competitive programming. All looked good but once when I was writing some programm in Python where was an error, when I ran it, output window(terminal)closed immediately and I can't saw the output.
Can you help me solve this problem somehow?
I will be glad for your advice.

Comment: Not without you showing us the code you made. General idea: use try/catch to print errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `journalctl -b-0` and the most recent boot information and error messages are displayed.

Then press the <kbd>End</kbd> key and the most recent messages are displayed. If you terminal closed abnormally I would expect an error message to appear.

You can use <kbd>Page Up</kbd> if the error occurred sometime ago.

Note this is for the current boot only. You need to have [multi-boot logging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025348/how-can-i-see-previous-history-prior-to-this-boot-in-journalctl) enabled to see previous boots. If you don't have it enabled you can view the file `/var/log/syslog` for pretty much the same information and error messages.