Ubuntu 24.04 shuts down after a few minutes
I've recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my new machine alongside Windows 11.
Initially the installation went smooth (after updating my UEFI to the latest version) and the setup seemed to function as expected.
However after a few hours of usage I experienced a green screen. My primary display suddenly turned black and the two secondary displays were solid green. No text or additional information displayed. After around half a minute the system rebooted.
Since this happened I have been facing stability issues. A few minutes after booting into Ubuntu, the system shuts off abruptly with no message or proper shutting down process. Just immediately turning black and starting up again. I do not have this issue on Windows 11.
How can I diagnose this issue? What would be the first steps to take here?
Unfortunately similar topics raised on this site haven't been able to resolve my issue.
Following hardware:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D
Motherboard: MSI B650 GAMING PLUS WIFI (MS-7E26)
GPU: AMD Radeon 7900 XTX


Please use journalctl command to see what exactly happened before the former shut-off, this link can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025348/how-can-i-see-previous-history-prior-to-this-boot-in-journalctl, then paste the output here

You can see the log entries just before the last crash with sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e. Read man journalctl.

I receive following logs: https://pastebin.com/g2tWz1Xk. It looks like Discord is failing to be updated by snap. Could this cause a crash? There were some other logs caused by errors in the "Dash to Dock" GNOME extension which I disabled in response. After removing the extension the system seems to crash after roughly 5 instead of 1 minutes.

Crawling through /var/log/syslog I also found following output which happened directly before a bunch of services started to stop: https://pastebin.com/ghXZBkvy

The issue turned out to be the two GNOME extensions "Ubuntu AppIndicators" and "Dash to Dock". They were crashing the shell and thus prompted a reboot of the system.
"Ubuntu AppIndicators" seems to have an issue with Discord's notification item and is crashing due to it.
I have not been able to find the cause of "Dash to Dock" crashing.
Disabling these two extensions resolved the stability issues. Sometimes the system freezes on the login screen after booting but that happens rarely and is fixed by rebooting. No freezing is taking place anymore while actively using the system.

Same issue here.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1523167/1545080
You can try to use below solution. It solved mine but it is not a concrete solution. It basically give Discord access to prevent occurring Denial process related to a bug.
sudo snap connect discord:system-observe

