Ubuntu 24.04 reboots itself
After upgrading from Ubuntu 23 to 24 LTS, I'm experiencing strange behavior with random reboots (black screen and reboot).
What I know:

It only reboots if Discord is running.
It reboots after 20-30-40 minutes.
Everything works fine on Ubuntu 23.
A full Ubuntu reinstall (with disk formatting) does not solve the problem
I found something similar here (Ubuntu 24.04 shuts down after a few minutes) but it did not solve the problem

Any ideas?

This type of problem is typically random and results of searches online for similar situations are unlikely to be relevant.  IT could be a hardware issue, or running out of ram, or even a corrupt or malicious discord binary.

@user10489, then why doesn't this happen in Ubuntu 23?

coincidence?  maybe 23 needed less memory?  bad device driver?  who knows.  Need more debug info, which is hard if it just reboots.

I have 32GB of RAM and its usage is normal. So I don't think it's a memory issue. I'm confused because I can't find anything like this on the forums. So you are right that it could be a driver or hardware issue.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513426/ubuntu-24-04-shuts-down-after-a-few-minutes  Gnome extensions caused the problem.

I had a similiar problem that was annoying me once a day or two. There is a system level problem. It is related either your GPU drivers or some of applications installed via Snapstore.
The First (easier solution): If you use snap-store and using Discord on your system it is likely the problem is related with a bug on AppArmor.
solution is here:
sudo snap connect discord:system-observe

if you want to learn more about the cause then check this:
Issue related AppArmor
or
in GPU case follow the steps below:
check the latest updates if it started after an update:
cat /var/log/apt/history.log

in my case these are the changed

libgl1-mesa-dri

libglx-mesa0

libegl-mesa0

libglapi-mesa

libgbm1

libxatracker2

mesa-vdpau-drivers




all graphic related updates. (I use Nvdia drivers too)
I've checked the available packages in my computer.
apt-cache madison libgl1-mesa-dri libglx-mesa0 libegl-mesa0 libglapi-mesa libgbm1 libxatracker2 mesa-vdpau-drivers

then downgrade them 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri=24.0.5-1ubuntu1 libglx-mesa0=24.0.5-1ubuntu1 libegl-mesa0=24.0.5-1ubuntu1 libglapi-mesa=24.0.5-1ubuntu1 libgbm1=24.0.5-1ubuntu1 libxatracker2=24.0.5-1ubuntu1 mesa-vdpau-drivers=24.0.5-1ubuntu1

if you like you can prevent them to upgrade onwards:
`sudo apt-mark hold libgl1-mesa-dri libglx-mesa0 libegl-mesa0 libglapi-mesa libgbm1 libxatracker2 mesa-vdpau-drivers`


Sorry, how that go from "Discord's AppArmor configuration is spammy" to "Snaps cause reboots"?

I am having the same problem on my fresh install of Ubuntu 24.01.1, I got Nvidia GTX 1080Ti and using the 'nvidia-driver-550 driver' option under 'Software and Updates' -> 'Additional Drivers'.
I already know discord might be the problem, so I don't install it.  I also think Chrome might be the issue, so I disable Chrome 'Use graphics acceleration when available'.
If I still randomly reboot, I will use another Nvidia driver, probably version 535 under 'Software and Updates' -> 'Additional Drivers'.  If that still doesn't work, I'll use the 'Ubuntu on Wayland' option in the login screen.
